# Dynamically setting initial location on expo MapView

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, location

I am trying to set the initial location of an expo MapView for a project of mine and am having trouble sending the longitude and latitude variables from the getlocation() call. I have tried sending the coordinates as variables, as they are and the best I get is a crashed app. Is there any way to make the initial region dynamically change based on the user's location whenever they open the screen?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Platform, Text, View, StyleSheet , SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
import {FAB, Title} from 'react-native-paper';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
import { homeStyle } from './Home.Style';

export const HomeScreen = () => {
    const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
    const [latitude, setLatitude] = useState(null);
    const [longitude, setLongitude] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
          let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
          setLatitude(location.coords.latitude)
          setLongitude(location.coords.longitude);
          setLocation(location.coords);
        })();
      }, []);

      console.warn("latitude: ", latitude);
      console.warn("longitude: ", longitude);
return(
    <View style = {homeStyle.flex}>
        <MapView
            style = {homeStyle.flex}
            initialRegion={{
                latitude: 0,
                longitude: 0,
                longitudeDelta: 0,
                latitudeDelta: 0
            }}/>
        <FAB 
        icon="plus"
        style = {homeStyle.fab}
        />
    </View>
)
}
```

This screen is accessed through a button press on another screen. I currently have the initial region latitude and longitude set to dummy data for initial testing.

I have tried sending variables with the latitude/longitude coordinates which led to a crash, I have tried sending the location.coords.latitude and location.coords.longitude directly to the same result.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible scenario which should cause app to crash:

1. Request device location before access permission granted.
2. Coordinates cached and stringified for quick retrieval on next request. react-native always expect coordinate value to be type of number (float).

New implementation handle those 2 possible edge-case:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { Platform, Text, View, StyleSheet, SafeAreaView } from "react-native";
import MapView from "react-native-maps";
import { FAB, Title } from "react-native-paper";
import * as Location from "expo-location";
import { homeStyle } from "./Home.Style";

export const HomeScreen = () => {
  const mapRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== "granted") {
        console.warn("Permission to access location was denied");
        return;
      }

      let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});

      if (location?.coords) {
        // Pre-cached location are stringified which should be a STRING
        // value and cause app to crash. Parse them to Number(float) value
        const latitude = parseFloat(location.coords.latitude);
        const longitude = parseFloat(location.coords.longitude);

        // Gradually animate map to user position
        const region = {
          latitudeDelta: 0.0092,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0092,
          latitude,
          longitude,
        };
        mapRef.current?.animateToRegion(region, 1000);
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={homeStyle.flex}>
      <MapView
        ref={mapRef}
        style={homeStyle.flex}
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: 0,
          longitude: 0,
          longitudeDelta: 0,
          latitudeDelta: 0,
        }}
      />
      <FAB icon="plus" style={homeStyle.fab} />
    </View>
  );
};
```